# SQL Server : query to displays days since last visit. Can optimize this and/or use in-built SQL function to avoid self join and simply the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2

Following is a simple table with only two columns `patientid` (id of a patient) and `visitdate` (date when patient visited the clinic) in SQL Server.

Each row represents a patient visit. Created a table variable and inserted some dummy data for testing purpose below. Attempted to write a query that display the days since last (previous) visit against next to every visit. If there is no previous visit, query is displaying display null and sorting by partientid and visit date (desc).

Can this query be further optimized? Also, can we avoid self join and use any SQL Server built-in construct/support/function to simplify the query. Any help will be appreciated.

```
declare @patientvisits table
(
    patientid int,
    visitdate datetime
)

insert into @patientvisits 
values (1, dateadd(day, -7, getdate())),
       (1, dateadd(day, -20, getdate())),
       (1, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())),
       (1, dateadd(day, -4, getdate())),
       (2, dateadd(day, -19, getdate())),
       (2, dateadd(day, -8, getdate())),
       (2, dateadd(day, -5, getdate())),
       (3, dateadd(day, -40, getdate())),
       (3, dateadd(day, -9, getdate())),
       (3, dateadd(day, -3, getdate())),
       (3, dateadd(day, -1, getdate())),
       (3, dateadd(day, 0, getdate()))

SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         VisitsA.patientid, VisitsA.visitdate "Visit Date", 
         CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, VisitsB.visitdate, VisitsA.visitdate) AS varchar(10)) "Last Visit (days)"
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patientid ORDER BY visitdate DESC) rowid, 
              patientid, visitdate
          FROM 
              @patientvisits) VisitsA 
     CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patientid ORDER BY visitdate DESC) rowid, 
              patientid, visitdate
          FROM 
              @patientvisits) VisitsB
     WHERE 
         VisitsA.patientid = VisitsB.patientid 
         AND VisitsA.rowid + 1 = VisitsB.rowid

     UNION

     SELECT 
         patientid, MIN(visitdate) visitdate, 0 
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY patientid ORDER BY visitdate DESC) rowid,
              patientid, visitdate
          FROM 
              @patientvisits) Visits 
     GROUP BY
         patientid) Result
ORDER BY
    patientid, "Visit Date" DESC
```

Comment: SQL Query to displays days since last visit. Can we optimize this and/or use in-built SQL function in SQL server to avoid self join and simplify the query?

Comment: I would add a PatientVisitID as identity Primary Key

Comment: what version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: @DavidP, Why add an additional data column? Couldn't you create a composite key off patientid + visitdate and build an index on top of that?

Comment: Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is simpler and perform better based on provided sample data

Per execution plan, it is 4 times faster.

```
;with cte as (
select patientid, visitdate, (select max(visitdate) from @patientvisits 
where patientid = p.patientid and visitdate < p.visitdate) prevVisitDate
from @patientvisits p
)
select patientid, visitdate, DATEDIFF(day, prevVisitDate, visitdate) as 'Last Visit (days)'
from cte
order by patientid, visitdate desc
```

Answer (score 1):

`CROSS JOIN` plus join-condition in `WHERE` is the same as an Inner Join. Why do you cast the number of days as a `VarChar(10)`?

There's no need for UNION or repeating the same Select multiple times:

```
WITH cte as
  (
    SELECT row_number() over (partition by patientid order by visitdate desc) rowid, patientid, visitdate
    FROM patientvisits
  )
SELECT VisitsA.patientid, VisitsA.visitdate "Visit Date", cast(COALESCE(datediff(day, VisitsB.visitdate, VisitsA.visitdate), 0) as varchar(10)) "Last Visit (days)"
   FROM cte AS VisitsA LEFT JOIN 
   cte AS VisitsB
ON VisitsA.patientid = VisitsB.patientid and VisitsA.rowid + 1 = VisitsB.rowid
order by patientid, "Visit Date" desc
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2012+ has a [**LAG()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) function that can give you the previous visit date.

```
SELECT  *,
        COALESCE(DATEDIFF(DAY, LAG(visitdate) OVER (PARTITION BY patientid ORDER BY visitdate), visitdate), 0) "Last Visit (days)"
FROM    @patientvisits p
ORDER BY patientid,
         visitdate DESC
```

You can also use OUTER APPLY to get the previous visitdate and subtract the current visitdate from the previous visitdate to get the difference

```
SELECT  pv.patientid,
        pv.visitdate "Visit Date",
        COALESCE(DATEDIFF(dd, ppv.visitdate, pv.visitdate), 0) "Last Visit (days)"
FROM    @patientvisits pv
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(ppv.visitdate) visitdate
                     FROM   @patientvisits ppv 
                     WHERE  ppv.patientid = pv.patientid 
                            AND ppv.visitdate < pv.visitdate ) ppv
ORDER BY pv.patientid,
        pv.visitdate DESC
```